# Auto-incrementing INDIRECT function

Tags: excel

I am trying to auto increment a cell using dragging. Example ("what I want"):

```
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D24") // dragging down from here
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D25")
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D26")
```

(What it's doing):

```
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D24") // dragging down from here
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D24")
=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D24")
```

How can I make this auto-increment?

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D"&ROW()+x)` change x so it matches your first cell... drag down will work as you want it

Comment: Thanks! perfect answer to my question!

Comment: That would be an answer @DirkReichel

Comment: @DirkReichel I second Davesexcel. Could you please add that as an answer so that OP can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDIRECT("'3. Cost Center & Plant Area'!$D"&ROW()+x)` change x so it matches your first cell... drag down will work as you want it :)